# Insert new lines after the last line of a paragraph in a file using batch file

Tags: batch-file

I want to insert a line to the end of paragraph in file using a batch
script. In my file the line last of paragraph is not clear. It is
variable which has form "LoadModule name moduleName ".

new line: "LoadModule new_module module/mod_newmod.so"

my file input.conf

```
abc def xyz 

LoadModule foo_module libexec/mod_fooa.so
LoadModule proxy_module libexec/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule lmn_module libexec/mod_abc.so
LoadModule xyz_module libexec/mod_def.so

ExtendedStatus controls whether Apache will generate "full" status
```

and result:

```
abc def xyz 

LoadModule foo_module libexec/mod_fooa.so
LoadModule proxy_module libexec/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule lmn_module libexec/mod_abc.so
LoadModule xyz_module libexec/mod_def.so
LoadModule new_module module/mod_newmod.so

ExtendedStatus controls whether Apache will generate "full" status
```

A new line "LoadModule new_module module/mod_newmod.so" get inserted at last of LoadModule paragraph. 
Please suggest a solution for this. Thank so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "file=test.txt"
set "here="
for /f "delims=:" %%A in ('findstr /lnbc:"LoadModule" "%file%" 2^>nul') do set here=%%A
if defined here (
  >"%file%.new" (
    for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%A in ('findstr /n "^" "%file%"') do (
      echo(%%B
      if %%A==%here% echo(LoadModule new_module module/mod_newmod.so
    )
  )
  move /y "%file%.new" "%file%"
)
type "%file%"
```

This solution assumes that none of your existing lines begin with `:`. A different solution is required if any lines do begin with `:`.

***EDIT*** - Updated answer to do nothing if test.txt does not exist or if test.txt does not contain any existing line starting with "LoadModule".

Comment: And could you suggust for me about links to learn writing batch file?

Comment: @romeo8812 - If you get an answer that meets all your needs, you should accept the answer by clicking the check mark. Accepting an answer lets others know the question has been answered, it awards 2 points to you, and awards 15 points to the person that posted the accepted answer.

Comment: @romeo8812 - It should be near the upper left corner of the answer... My favorite link is http://www.dostips.com. Other good links are http://www.robvanderwoude.com/batchfiles.php, http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html and http://ss64.com/nt/

Comment: Yes. And if I want to check in my file exist "LoadModule new_module module/mod_newmod.so" -> will not insert new line to test.txt. What should i do?

Comment: Thanks @dbenham. I want to update my question. If in my file exist newline"LoadModule new_module module/mod_newmod.so" -> not insert newline. If in my file exist #newline "#LoadModule new_module module/mod_newmod.so"->insert newline. Please suggess a solution for this. Thanks so much.

Comment: @romeo8812 - I don't understand your new requirement. You can edit your original question (the grey "edit" link below your question), or perhaps ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks you. My english is not good. I have resolved my problems with using findstr.